# return any node with child nodes name matching multiple

Tags: xslt, parent, children

I want to retrieve any Node with the child nodes childTypeA, childTypeB  or childTypeC, but not return nodes with only other child nodes (like stepChildA).
Once I have that node, I can retrieve any of the child nodes and their attributes. But I can't figure how to filter out those nodes that do not have any child nodes matching childTypeA, childTypeB or childTypeC.
My efforts either return all nodes with children, or return a node for each matching child, which means the same node is returned one, two or three times, depending upon if there is one, two or all three of the desired child nodes.

With xml data as shown

```
<parent Name="Item one">
    <OtherData Name="Data one">
    <childTypeA>
        <someData Name="Child A">
    </childTypeA>
    <childTypeB>
        <someData Name="Child B">
    </childTypeB>
</parent>
<parent Name="Item two">
    <OtherData Name="Data two">
    <childTypeB>
        <someData Name="Child B">
    </childTypeB>
    <childTypeC>
        <someData Name="Child C">
    </childTypeC>
</parent>
<parent Name="Item three">
    <OtherData Name="Data three">
    <stepChildA>
        <someData Name="Step Child A">
    </stepChildA>
</parent>
```

The actual data under each child type is different and I'm trying to assemble it into a table, where each parent node with the desired child type appear on a single row and the child data align under the appropriate columns. Currently I've either had all parent nodes where the data desired appears as intended, but also includes rows with the other parent nodes which have no data, or, I am getting multiple rows when there is more than one of the desired child type. The specific child type data fall into the proper columns, but are not on one row.

My approach was correct, but I needed to re-order my code. I had the "if test" before the "for-each". By swapping them, I was able to return all parent nodes, but then use the "xsl:if test=..." to ignore the unwanted parents and build each table row as I parse through the child nodes. Note I added a sort to the returned parent nodes, based upon the value of their attribute @Name.

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent">
    <xsl:sort select="@Name">
    <xsl:if test="childTypeA or childTypeB or childTypeC">
        <tr>.........</tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My XML data is very verbose and I am trying not to overwhelm the post. I am also struggling with the formatting rules.

Comment: What have you tried so far (XSLT approach) ?

Comment: I had tried a choose when using boolean testing and that returned the parent node, one time for each matching child.
Then I tried a if test with the same boolean, followed by a for-each, which returned one row for each parent, but returned all parents.
Since posting, I tried swapping the order of the second approach and only created my table rows within the if test and that is now working.

Comment: That answer is not helping. What is your [mcve]?

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="parent">  
    <xsl:sort select="@Name">  
    <xsl:if test="childTypeA or childTypeB or childTypeC">  
        <tr>.........</tr>  
    </xsl:if>  
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: I apologize if I had expressed myself insufficiently: edit(!) your question with a clear, minimal XSLT stylesheet and a desired output XML. The input XML should be transformed to the output XML by the XSLT. The difference between your _actual_ output XML and your _desired_ output XML should also be clear and visible.

Comment: You need to close the <xsl:sort> tag in your example. There are similar problems in your input xml.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you simply need to use the xpath `parent[childTypeA | childTypeB | childTypeC]` like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent[childTypeA | childTypeB | childTypeC]">
  <xsl:sort..etc.

</xsl:for-each>
```